# Sade nav collapse from button from different component in angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

> Hi I have a sidenav but a button in different component . What i want
>   on click of that button from the x component sidenav should close and
>   open in angular.
>
> Please find the below working code.

Example when i click button from x component sidnev should expand or collapse.

Can some one provide the solution how to achieve this.

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";


body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}


a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}


ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}
a.article, a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
#content {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#content.active {
    width: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content.active {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
    /* for button right corner of the sidebar */
    #dismiss {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    /* top right corner of the sidebar */
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
            <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
            <nav id="sidebar">
               <div id="dismiss">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>
            </div>
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>NBCU Wireless System Administrator </h3>
                </div>

                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <p>Select Menu</p>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Maintain Equipment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Maintain Studio & Studio Frequency</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Maintain Studio Frequency</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Maintain Equipment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Maintain Studio & Studio Frequency</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Maintain Studio Frequency</a></li>
                    <!-- <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                
            </nav>
```